# Saiku-Clicking on New query not displaying anything

Tags: failed-installation, saiku

I downloaded saiku (Saiku Server 2.4 (Including Foodmart DB)) from the following link -http://analytical-labs.com/downloads.php.

Following the installation notes, I have downloaded latest Apache software, JDK. As per instructions if I now go to localhost 8080 I see log on page. Upon logging with username and password as admin and admin I am into the Saiku main page.

When I click on 'New Query' button nothing is happening. I am not able to see any Foodmart Databse or Dimensions or anything.

Can someone help me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working. Problem was after running start-saiku.bat file, the command prompt file was still running with 'Press enter to continue..'. Upon clicking this, the cmd prompt ended and now am able to browse through Saiku from localhost.